# trying run Raw queries using Ecto Elixir

Tags: elixir, ecto

I have such queries written in PostgreSQL.

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE keep AS
SELECT min(snapshot_timestamp) AS snapshot_timestamp
FROM   "andaz-rkugf"
WHERE  snapshot_timestamp <= '2018-10-31'
GROUP  BY extract(epoch FROM snapshot_timestamp)::bigint / 600
ORDER  BY 1;

CREATE INDEX ON keep (snapshot_timestamp);
ANALYZE keep;

DELETE FROM "andaz-rkugf" a
WHERE  snapshot_timestamp <= '2018-10-31'
AND    NOT EXISTS (
   SELECT FROM keep k
   WHERE a.snapshot_timestamp = k.snapshot_timestamp
   );
 
DROP TABLE pg_temp.keep;
```

I have a list of table names on which I want to run the above queries. I cannot run them all together as It throws errors, about the prepared statement.

but when I do it one by one as written below.

```
create_keep = """
CREATE TEMP TABLE \"keep\" AS
SELECT min(snapshot_timestamp) AS snapshot_timestamp
FROM   \"#{camera}\"
WHERE  snapshot_timestamp <= '2018-10-31'
GROUP  BY extract(epoch FROM snapshot_timestamp)::bigint / 600
ORDER  BY 1;
"""
create_index = """
CREATE INDEX ON \"keep\" (snapshot_timestamp);
"""

analyze = """
ANALYZE \"keep\";
"""

delete_snaphots = """
DELETE FROM \"#{camera}\" a
WHERE  snapshot_timestamp <= '2018-10-31'
AND    NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT FROM \"keep\" k
    WHERE a.snapshot_timestamp = k.snapshot_timestamp
    );
"""

drop_keep = """
DROP TABLE \"keep\";
"""
[create_keep, analyze, create_index, delete_snaphots, drop_keep]
|> Enum.each(fn query -> Ecto.Adapters.SQL.query(SnapshotsRepo, query, []) |> IO.inspect() end)
```

while passing `camera` as a parameter to the method in which the below code is written, I got such errors as

First query returns this

```
{:ok,
 %Postgrex.Result{
   columns: nil,
   command: :select,
   connection_id: 392760,
   messages: [],
   num_rows: 0,
   rows: nil
 }}
```

2:

```
{:error,
 %Postgrex.Error{
   connection_id: 392773,
   message: nil,
   postgres: %{
     code: :undefined_table,
     file: "namespace.c",
     line: "423",
     message: "relation \"keep\" does not exist",
     pg_code: "42P01",
     routine: "RangeVarGetRelidExtended",
     severity: "ERROR",
     unknown: "ERROR"
   },
   query: nil
 }}
```

3:

```
{:error,
 %Postgrex.Error{
   connection_id: 392796,
   message: nil,
   postgres: %{
     code: :undefined_table,
     file: "namespace.c",
     line: "423",
     message: "relation \"keep\" does not exist",
     pg_code: "42P01",
     routine: "RangeVarGetRelidExtended",
     severity: "ERROR",
     unknown: "ERROR"
   },
   query: nil
 }}
```

4:

```
{:error,
 %Postgrex.Error{
   connection_id: 392770,
   message: nil,
   postgres: %{
     code: :undefined_table,
     file: "tablecmds.c",
     line: "1188",
     message: "table \"keep\" does not exist",
     pg_code: "42P01",
     routine: "DropErrorMsgNonExistent",
     severity: "ERROR",
     unknown: "ERROR"
   },
   query: nil
 }}
```

So basically, the very first one is not even creating a new table `KEEP`. so all others are failing too.

I also tried to make it just keep instead of "keep".

can you point me to what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Temporary tables are automatically dropped when a session is closed. Maybe you can wrap the tasks in a transaction.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to wrap all of your `Ecto.Adapters.SQL.query()` calls inside of a `Repo.transaction(fn -> end)` that way your temp table and all the other queries are ran with in the same session. Temp tables are dropped at the end of each session so that is why its not able to be accessed